# Very simple : Mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in place:

`RewriteRule ^register/?$ /fitch/index.php?cmd=register [NC,L,QSA]`

Requests to `mysite.com/register` are rewritten to

`mysite.com/fitch/index.php?cmd=register`

I want to allow an optional parameter to be passed as well, such that requests to
`mysite.com/register/sender=models` directs me to

`mysite.com/fitch/index.php?cmd=register&sender=models`

Comment: Is the name of the optional variable always `sender`? If so, wouldn't it be better to have your visitor request `/register/models` instead? Otherwise your optional URL is little cleaner than a standard request with a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
RewriteRule ^register/(.*) /fitch/index.php?cmd=register&$1
```

Answer (score 0):

For any number of paths -> query string params:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1&$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register&
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fitch/index.php?cmd=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite URL's like:

```
http://mysite.com/register/a=b/1=2/c=d
```

to:

```
http://mysite.com/fitch/index.php?cmd=register&a=b&1=2&c=d
```